# Multithread in a java image processing program

Tags: java, multithreading, image-processing

I have an image processing program which is implemented using multithreading. My processor is simple Intel Dual core of 1.73GHZ. I did some experiments by running my program using diffrent number of threads, and i noted that the processing time decreases substantially until nbthread is equal to 200. over 200 there is no more decreasing in time.

Dual Core processors have only two computing units, so, how one can explain the obtained results?

Comment: That depends what on your threads are doing.

Comment: If you process is CPU bound, the optimal is likely to 2. For an network IO bound process, many more threads can be useful.

Comment: @SLaks Each one performs The Region Growing algorithm in a portion of the image

Comment: That doesn't tell us nearly enough.  Show us your code.

Comment: I've played with multi-thread image processing and I've found that once I go one or two threads over my processor threads I get a decrease in performance with the overhead of thread synchronization. What is your code doing to get 100 times the number of threads running correctly. Can you show some of your code?

Comment: each thread has a start point (pixel), it analyses its neighbors and if they are ok with a predefined criterion they are stored and the same process is applied to each one of them